# How to count the number of operations in an if statement. Java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, operations

For this assignment I have to count the number of operations that my program does. I have put an OpCount counter in my loops etc., but am stumped on how to do so for an if statement. Heres my code for the ifs for some context (Printing details of a specific dam from an array of objects of type dam):

```
public void printDam(String damName)    {


boolean find = false;
    for (int i = 0; i<211; i++)   {
        ObjDam dam = data[i];
        if (dam.getDamName().equals(damName)) {
            System.out.println("Dam Name: " + dam.getDamName() +
                ", FSC: " + dam.getFsc() +
                ", Dam Level: " + dam.getDamLevel());
            find = true;
        }
    }
    if (find == false)  {
        System.out.println("The dam " + damName + " you entered cannot be found in the file");
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are *precisely* **212** `if`s in this code. (211 + 1).

Comment: So what operations do you think your program performs?  Can you list them for us?

Comment: Define "operation".